# Background Hosted Service executing twice in .net core. Any solution?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cron, background-service

I have created one background hosted service in .net core 3.1, and based on CRON expression, it is expected to run at desired time. i.e. 3 AM through Mon-Fri. Everything seems to be working fine, the background service is running at desired time, but when it runs, it always runs twice. The app is hosted on IIS.

Here is the code which I am using:

In Startup File, ConfigureServices Methods:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyTestBackgroundHostedService>();
```

Here is my service configured:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NCrontab;
using Serilog;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyTestBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly CrontabSchedule _schedule;
        private readonly string _scheduleDetail;
        private DateTime _nextRun;
        private ILogger _logger;

        public MyTestBackgroundService(ILogger logger)
        {
            _scheduleDetail = "0 0 3 * * 0";
            _schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(_scheduleDetail, new CrontabSchedule.ParseOptions { IncludingSeconds = true });
            _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            do {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                if (now > _nextRun) {
                    _logger.Information($"MyTestBackgroundService job started at {now}", now);
                    Process();
                    _logger.Information($"MyTestBackgroundService :MyTestBackgroundService job finished at {now}", now);
                    _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
                }

                await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
            }
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        private void Process()
        {
            try {
                // do something
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                _logger.Error($"MyTestBackgroundService failed : {ex}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it's executed twice, but your implementation is very inefficient. I'd recommend calculating the time difference between the next execution and `now` and setting a timer to execute the callback when needed instead of testing the time every 5 sec.

Answer (score 2):

Root cause for above problem was:

Background service is configured in our API solution, and  API was running on multiple instances, hence resulting in multiple background services running in parallel, which was error prone in our case.

Solution:

1. Either limit the running instances, but that could not be practical as it may result in performance issues.
2. Background service should have been configured in a dedicated project.